# awk, sed - отсеять строки, если в определенном поле строки нет нужного количества символов

Tags: sed, awk

Как выбрать только нужное поле строки и задать (не)строгое соответствие по количеству символов в нем, понимаю. Проблем сваять bash скрипт чтобы выполнял задачу, изложенную в вопросе, тоже нет. Однако, возможно есть более простое и лаконичное решение одной командой, больше наверное это работа все же для awk.
Имеем текст со строками вида:

```
XXXXX:YYYYY:ZZZZ
XXXX:YYY:ZZZZ
XXX:YYYYY:ZZZ
```

Задача: выбрать из текста только строки, в которых в первом поле количество символов X равно строго только 5-ти, все остальные строки отсеять.
То есть нужно в примере получить:

```
XXXXX:YYYYY:ZZZZ
```

Отсев строк должен производиться именно по нужному количеству символов нужного поля, сами символы роли не должны играть (разделитель полей известен и пусть останется `:` ). Спасибо.

Comment: А почему собственно не `grep`? Вроде ж как раз для него задача?

Comment: `sed -r -n 's/^([X]{5}:.*)$/\1/gp' ./file.txt` так еще по идее сработает, `grep -P '^[X]{5}:' ./file.txt` тоже должно сработать

Comment: Ваш код работает, но вы не заметили что символы не только X а любые произвольные. Если заменить тут `5` на `*` как-то...

Comment: А буквы одинаковые должны быть или любая последовательность?

Comment: sed будет выглядеть следующим образом `sed -r -n 's/^([A-Za-z]){5}:/&/p' ./file.txt` если последовательность из одинаковых букв или `sed -r -n 's/^[A-Za-z]{5}:/&/p' ./file.txt` если любая последовательность букв

Comment: мысль понятна, а есть возможность все же вписать что-то типа * (любой) ?  [:print:] ?

Comment: Да, шаблон замены сделать так `'s/^(.)\1{4}:/&/p'` должно сработать? но все сломается если выбранным символом будет :, тут он выберет любую последовательность больше 5, есть смысл защититься от этого к примеру исключив из выборки 's/^([^:])\1{4}:/&/p', вообщем на что фантазии хватит))) Протестировать мне негде, в любом случае гарантированно рабочий вариант с awk у вас есть.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы не показали, что у вас есть сейчас.  У меня:

```sh
$ awk -F ':' '$1 == "XXXXX" { print $0; }' ./file.txt
```

Вариант для любых букв:

```sh
$ awk -F ':' 'length($1) == 5 { print $0; }' ./file.txt
```

Comment: Спасибо за наводку. Правильный ответ думаю тут `awk -F ':' 'length($1) == 5 { print $0; }' ./file.txt`

Comment: Проглядел про любые буквы.  Добавил ваш вариант в ответ.